# FFMPEG Directories and Varables

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frames

Running this produces an error. What Am I doing wrong?

```
read YYYY MM DD <<<$(date +'%Y %m %d')
for f in "$@"
do
  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf fps=1/8 "/Volumes/Backup/VideoFrames/$YYYY $MM $DD/${f%.*}Frame55Grab%d.png"
done
```

Comment: You should show us the actual error–otherwise it makes it harder to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Not sure if your images are really named `Frame55Grab%d.png`?! Is that `%d` intended?

Comment: No, the filename I want to export is "{YYYY MM DD}/(file name}Frame55Grab{number}"